# How to change Gazebo GUI focal length/FOV

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to change the focal length/field of view of the camera used to render the Gazebo GUI?  The default focal length looks really short, which has the tragic effect of making my planning scenario look easy to reviewers :(  I've noticed there is a camera tag in the world file, but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12658/how-to-change-gazebo-gui-focal-length/fov/) by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Paul!

Somewhere within the gazebo robot configuration you will find the camera parameters like the following:
Changing the hfov will change you the field of view :-)

```
<sensor:camera name="cam_front_sensor">
  <imageSize>640 480</imageSize>
  <imageFormat>B8G8R8</imageFormat>
  <hfov>90</hfov>
  <nearClip>0.1</nearClip>
  <farClip>100</farClip>
  <updateRate>20.0</updateRate>
  .....
</sensor:camera>
```

You can compute the focal length with

f = (width/2)  / tan( deg2rad(hfov)/2) = (640/2) / tan(deg2rad(90)/2) = 320

The example above will give you a focal length of 320. Don't forget to convert the angle to radiant

Greetings
Markus
[image: Gazebo camera FOV vs. focal length]

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, the camera used for rendering the gui does not have an easy way to change its FOV.

Ticketed [feature request](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/39) needs to be released.

Alternatively, you can create a static camera model in the world and set its fov as Markus described, and screen capture the images separately using [image_view](http://ros.org/wiki/image_view) or [rviz](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2